# Is "buffeted" the AmE version of the BrE word "buffetted"?

Tags: verbs, american-english, british-english, orthography, doubled-consonants

I am referring to the use of the verb "[to buffet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buffet)" meaning

> "(especially of wind or waves) strike repeatedly and violently; batter."

The use of "buffeted" and "buffeting" is widespread.  However use of "buffetted" and "buffetting" still occurs.  There is, incidentally, a huge ratio in favour of the single "t" ([about 4:1 200 years ago, currently about 60:1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buffetted%2Cbuffeted&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuffetted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffeted%3B%2Cc0)).

However, to my British eye, the single "t" looks wrong though, in a similar way to "travelers" and "travellers" being the AmE and BrE spellings.

Some websites list the double "t" spelling, but I've yet to find any that qualify it as being British.  Nor do they label it as obsolete, archaic or any of the other indications that I should ignore my feelings and accept the single "t" as the currently accepted spelling. N.B. I am deliberately avoiding the word "correct" :-)

---

Curiously, I've just found a [1764 English - French dictionary](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=k7c_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PP648&lpg=PP648&dq=buffetted%20dictionary&source=bl&ots=Fa1tj5hJul&sig=SuvFwjXPMk31zFGF_Cz17Ux_N5s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlyqvc9PHcAhWJbMAKHUIoCeg4ChDoATADegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=buffetted%20dictionary&f=false) that translates "buffetted" as "*soufleté*" in French, a word which is now spelled with a double "f" as "*souffleté" (meaning "slapped" or similar). I love how fluid language is over time.

Comment: Apparently there is little usage difference between AmE and BrE:  ***buffeted*** -  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buffeted%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbuffeted%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuffeted%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffeted%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0 - ***buffetted*** - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buffetted%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbuffetted%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuffetted%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffetted%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This is quite interesting, actually. The general rule – that polysyllabics only double their final consonant if the final syllable is stressed _or_ (in BrE) the final consonant is an L – doesn’t seem to be quite consistent in words ending in /ət ~ ɪ̵t/. _Buffetting_, _cossetting_, and _rivetting_ do occur (though infrequently), but _*marketting_, _*pocketting_, and _*ferretting_ are completely nonexistent, as far as I can tell.

Comment: You said, «any of the other indications that I should ignore my feelings and accept the double "t" as the currently accepted spelling».  Did you mean, «any of the other indications that I should ignore my feelings and accept the ***single*** "t" as the currently accepted spelling»?

Comment: @Scott well spotted, I'll edit to correct.

Answer (score 7):

Actually all online dictionaries suggest *buffeting* and *buffeted* with ***one single  “t”*** as present participle, simple past, and and past participle of to buffet. Only [wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/buffet#Verb)  mentions the alternative ***double t*** forms.

Checking with Google Books it appears that it is not an [AmE vs BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buffetted%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbuffetted%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuffetted%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffetted%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) issue, but rather [an archaic usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buffetted%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbuffetted%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuffetted%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuffetted%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0), present in the Bible for instance, that may have survived as non-standard form.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this has to do with the rules for doubling final consonants, and nothing to do with AmE or BrE.

According to [Ann Carr at Owlcation](https://owlcation.com/humanities/DOUBLING-CONSONANT-RULES-To-Double-or-Not-to-Double-a-question-answered-Short-Long-Vowels-Doubling-Consonants),

> Rule 4: Don't Double in a Root Word With More Than One Syllable When Last Syllable Not Stressed
>
> In a word with more than one syllable there is no doubling of the last consonant unless the stress is on the last syllable.

[image: double consonants]

[Merriam-Webster learner's dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/Doubling-the-final-consonant-before-adding-ed-or-ing) gives the same rule:

> In a word with 2 or more syllables, double the final consonant ONLY if the word ends in 1 vowel + 1 consonant AND the final syllable is stressed.

[BBC Skillswise - English and Maths for adults](http://www.bbc.co.uk/skillswise/factsheet/en17suff-l1-f-suffix-spelling-rules-double-letters) confirms this too (see rule 4).

[image: Doubling consonants]

[Study.com](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-a-double-consonant-words-rule.html) has a great video explaining the consonant rules